# Flyway and Maven integration - Cannot access s3://flyway-repo/release

Tags: oracle, maven, flyway

I want to integrate flyway with maven and oracle db. At first I want to make a simple test if there are simple migrations possible, so I made a build part of pom file as the following (as described in [flyway official page](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/)):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</url>
                <user>test</user>
                <password>test</password>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>TEST</schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
                    <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But when I'm trying to run flyway:migrate or flyway:info goal, I'm getting the following error, which I do not know with what is connected..

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:4.2.0:info (default-cli) on project gwm-admin: Execution default-cli of goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:4.2.0:info failed: Plugin org.fl
ywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:4.2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.4.0 from/to flyway-repo-private (s3://flyway-repo/release): Canno
t access s3://flyway-repo/release with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access s3://flyway-repo/release using the registered transporter factorie
s: WagonTransporterFactory: java.util.NoSuchElementException
[ERROR]       role: org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon
[ERROR]   roleHint: s3
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Try to install oracle jdbc driver in your local maven repository. [mvn install:install-file](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)
`mvn install:install-file -Dfile={Path/to/your/ojdbc14.jar} -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.0.4.0 -Dpackaging=jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wrote @Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz in comment, oracle jdbc driver need to be added manually. More informations about could be found here : [mkyong post](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/)

On the other hand, after the driver was added I got another error which can be resolved by moving a dependency out of plugin part into main dependencies of pom.xml file

Comment: Oracle JDBC drivers are available on Oracle Maven repository.  Please follow the instructions on this blog (https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides) to download the same.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source> java version </maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target> java version </maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Fly way -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
           <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
           <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                (...)
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```